# R - Logistic regression: how to prepare data

Tags: r, logistic

I've been doing a lot of googling on logistic regression but I've been getting confused more and more so please help me out.

The data set I have
The outcomes of interest (dependent variables) are

1. Are admissions 'potentially preventable hospitalisations' (PPH) - Yes/no
2. Are the patients admitted or discharged within a day -  Admitted/ Discharged

My Independent varibles are

1. Migration status (Australian, Migrants, Refugees)
2. Socio-economic Status (Low, High)
3. Age (<20, 20-35 >35)

Here are the problems I have with my data set.

1. I have about 6000 data for Australians, 1000 for migrants and 200 for refugees. Is this too big of an imblance to conduct logistic regression?
2. For PPH outcome I have about 300 NAs, mostly from the Australian data - Im assuming this is because they have more sample so they are more likely to have NAs, but I wasnt sure if I should removed them or not. I have heard for data analysis removing data is only done if really necessary. Also a I have a similar concern as 1. where the rate of PPH is approximately 500, 10, 100 for Australians, refugees and migrants. I would like some advice on how to approach this data.

Other problems are more fundamentally Logistic regression related,

1. Setting the data type as a factor.

I've converted Admitted ~ 1, and discharged ~ 0 and set the data type as an integer.

```
C_ALL_analysis <- C_ALL_analysis %>% 
mutate(Admitted_log = case_when(
admitted_group == "Admitted" ~ 1, 
admitted_group == "Discharged" ~ 0))
```

Since the outcome of interest for me is admitted, and I want my results in terms of admitted is this the right things to do? Or am I suppose to convert admitted ~ 0 and Discharged ~ 1 to get my results in terms of admitted?

Or can I keep my data as characters (admitted/ discharged), convert the variable into factors?
But if I do convert them into factors, how do I know if the results is in reference 'admitted' or discharged?

This is the code I put and the results I got

```
C_ALL_analysis$age_group <- as.factor(C_ALL_analysis$age_group)
C_ALL_analysis$country_group <- as.factor(C_ALL_analysis$country_group)
C_ALL_analysis$IRSD_group <- as.factor(C_ALL_analysis$IRSD_group)
C_ALL_analysis$admitted_group <-as.factor(C_ALL_analysis$admitted_group)
C_ALL_analysis$Admitted_log <-as.integer(C_ALL_analysis$Admitted_log)

str(C_ALL_analysis)
> $ age_group     : Factor w/ 3 levels "<20",">35","21-34": 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 ...
  $ IRSD_group    : Factor w/ 2 levels "High","Low": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
  $ country_group : Factor w/ 3 levels "AUS","HSC","NHSC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ admitted_group: Factor w/ 2 levels "Admitted","Discharged": 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
  $ Admitted_log  : int  1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
```

** i will use admitted_group which i set as a factor

```
mymodel <- glm(admitted_group ~ country_group, data = C_ALL_analysis, family = "binomial")
summary(mymodel)

>Call:
  glm(formula = admitted_group ~ country_group, family = "binomial", 
  data = C_ALL_analysis)

  Deviance Residuals: 
     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
  -1.346  -1.221   1.078   1.134   1.134  

  Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  (Intercept)        0.10306    0.02573   4.006 6.17e-05 ***
  country_groupHSC   0.28422    0.15280   1.860   0.0629 .  
  country_groupNHSC  0.13515    0.06738   2.006   0.0449 *  
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

   Null deviance: 10074  on 7288  degrees of freedom
   Residual deviance: 10067  on 7286  degrees of freedom
   AIC: 10073

   Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

exp(coef(mymodel))
>      (Intercept)  country_groupHSC country_groupNHSC 
          1.108559          1.328727          1.144711 
exp(confint(mymodel))
>                       2.5 %   97.5 %
  (Intercept)       1.0540699 1.165917
  country_groupHSC  0.9869982 1.798492
  country_groupNHSC 1.0033086 1.306693
```

From this result I want to confirm the interpretation of my result.

The odds ratio of Australians being admitted to hospital is 1.108559, with p-value of 6.17e-05. The confidece interval of the odds ratio is (1.0540699-1.165917).
Is this interpretation of the data correct?

After this I am planning to run a second logistic regression to work out the adjusted odds ratio

```
mymodel <- glm(admitted_group ~ country_group + age_group + IRSD_group, data = C_ALL_analysis, family = "binomial")
```

2. Since the aim for me is not to build a model, but to analyse my data, is it necessary for me to split my data into train and test data?

Sorry I am very new to statistics in general so this questions may sound pretty basic, but please help me out!

Comment: I suggest you read a basic statistic book first like [Introductory Statistics](https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/introduction-to-statistics)

Comment: yes yes that is true, I have been going crazy with online resources that are not clear enough for me to understand. I guess my main question is the part about the setting my outcome variable as a factor or a interger.

Comment: Most of the internet websites have suggested converting the variable as a factor, but I just don't understand how to interpret to data is that case, like is logistic regression result in terms of admitted or is it in terms of discharge.

Comment: Stop coding and start reading Andrew Gelman & Jennifer Hill, _Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models_ :)

Comment: I see 4 or 5 questions packed inside and it's really hard to address it down in 1 answer. Below I address the question related to logistic regression

Comment: As for the question on imbalance and data NA, I suggest you post it as another question

Comment: @StupidWolf  I'm just not sure what you are referring to as below. But about the NAs, I will take up your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @Sergio I am reading the book now thanks for the recommendations too

Comment: I (just) posted an answer below that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to answer your questions.

> Since the outcome of interest for me is admitted, and I want my
> results in terms of admitted is this the right things to do? Or am I
> suppose to convert admitted ~ 0 and Discharged ~ 1 to get my results
> in terms of admitted?
>
> Or can I keep my data as characters (admitted/ discharged), convert
> the variable into factors? But if I do convert them into factors, how
> do I know if the results is in reference 'admitted' or discharged?

Yes the "success" or the category you are interested in can be coded as 0/1. If you want to keep it a factor, you can specify the levels, the first one is always the reference. i use an example as you did not provide your data:

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(
admitted_group = sample(c("Admitted","Discharged"),100,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.3,0.7)),
country_group= sample(c("AUS","HSC","NHSC"),100,replace=TRUE)
,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#make a binary response
df$admitted_binary = ifelse(df$admitted_group == "Admitted",1,0)

coefficients(glm(admitted_binary ~ country_group,family="binomial",data=df))
      (Intercept)  country_groupHSC country_groupNHSC 
       -0.8266786        -0.3127557        -0.3970969 

# make it a factor, reference is "Discharged"
df$admitted_group = factor(df$admitted_group,levels=c("Discharged","Admitted"))


coefficients(glm(admitted_group ~ country_group,family="binomial",data=df))
      (Intercept)  country_groupHSC country_groupNHSC 
       -0.8266786        -0.3127557        -0.3970969
```

In this case, the intercept is -0.8266786 and because you have three groups, the intercept refers to log-odds for the group `"AUS"`. So you can check it, using the amazing `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
select(country_group,admitted_binary) %>% 
group_by(country_group) %>% 
summarize(prob=mean(admitted_binary)) %>% 
mutate(log_odds=log(prob/(1-prob)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  country_group  prob log_odds
  <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 AUS           0.304   -0.827
2 HSC           0.242   -1.14 
3 NHSC          0.227   -1.22
```

To answer this:

> Since the aim for me is not to build a model, but to analyse my data,
> is it necessary for me to split my data into train and test data?

You don't need to split into train and test. If you suspect the model is overfitting, i.e the coefficient estimates are biased towards some observation, run a bootstrap.